# How to use php-cs-fixer in vscode with docker container for php and composer

Tags: java, php, laravel, docker, visual-studio-code

#### Goal

I want to use php-cs-fixer + .php_cs config file for defining rules - without having to install PHP on my host machine.

---

#### Issue

I am using PHP7.3 inside of a docker container - this is also where composer is installed. This means I do not have php running on my local machine.

Extensions for vscode - like junstyle's [php-cs-fixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer) seemed to require that the executable, config file, and current working directory are localized. I could not get this to work.

---

#### Context

- Running local development with docker container for php & composer (docker for mac, using docker-compose)
- Project is a Laravel API - has [`friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) installed with composer required for dev
- Using vscode, with extension: [Simple PHP CS Fixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=calebporzio.simple-php-cs-fixer)
- I have a .php_cs config file at the root of my project
- I have successfully ran `/var/www/site/app/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --verbose --config=/var/www/site/.php_cs {PATH TO MY FILE I WANT TO FIX}` as a proof of concept from within the docker container. It worked perfectly.

  - `/var/www/site/` is the path inside the container that maps to my `~/code/project` on my host machine

---

#### "Close, but not close enough" Solution

- [PHP-Storm PHP-CS-Fixer & Docker](https://atomy1337.medium.com/phpstorm-with-php-cs-fixer-and-docker-and-keybind-5418b1c5cb9)

This blog post gave a tip about making a script eg `/usr/local/bin/docker-phpcs with the following contents (and chmod +x to make it executable)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/docker-compose exec -T app-php /var/www/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer "$@"
```

But, I couldn't get this to work, even when defining the vscode setting for the junstyle extension from `"php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "php-cs-fixer"`  to `"php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "/usr/local/bin/docker-phpcs",`

This gave me a ton of:

```
[2021-04-12 18:36:39.174] [exthost] [error] [junstyle.php-cs-fixer] provider FAILED
[2021-04-12 18:36:39.174] [exthost] [error] undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

## Update: New Solution

Skip to the `tldr;` section below for direct solution. Otherwise, enjoy:

I had to accept that there were *no php-cs-fixer vscode plugins* that would work with solving the path difference between my host machine and docker container.

I got deep into the weeds and I forked [Simple PHP CS FIXER](https://github.com/amurrell/simple-php-cs-fixer) adding a few more configuration options:

- **executablePath** - relative to my host machine so I could use a script in my project. eg. `/Users/me/myproject/docker-phpcs` - this project was originally hardcoding `php-cs-fixer` here. That is still the default in my version.

  Here's an example script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  docker exec -t "mycontainer" /var/www/site/app/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer $@
  ```

  *Note: I made sure to `chmod +x` on my script to make it executable*
- **hostPath** - so I could tell it my project path eg. "/Users/me/code/myproject/"
- **dockerPath** - so I could tell it my docker container path eg. "/var/www/site"

Then I modified the extension.js to **replace** the **hostName** with the **dockerPath** in the following files:

- the **config file**, if one is set.
- the **document-being-saved's** fileName.

So when using this, I create my settings per-folder like this:

```
"simple-php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "/Users/me/code/myproject/docker-phpcs",
"simple-php-cs-fixer.config": ".php_cs",
"simple-php-cs-fixer.hostPath": "/Users/me/code/myproject",
"simple-php-cs-fixer.dockerPath": "/var/www/site",
```

And I purposefully do not force this on save - and instead made a key-binding for the plugin's command (ctrl+s, instead of cmd + s), so I can control when I want to completely obliterate my file.

## tldr;

I forked the plugin to provide options for docker-relative paths and custom executable path to php-cs-fixer - I also did make a PR to the plugin - but if that does not get accepted... you can side load the extension like so:

1. "install" the plugin using marketplace as normal
2. go to your extensions folder (on my mac it was $HOME/.vscode/extensions
3. `git clone git@github.com:amurrell/simple-php-cs-fixer.git`
4. remove the one installed by marketplace like: `calebporzio.simple-php-cs-fixer-x.x.x`

Hopefully PR gets accepted...

In the meantime, with ctrl+s key-binding and this modified plugin with extra settings, I now get a fixed file according to my configuration, using my docker-container.

---

## Another Close Solution

**Update**: This was not really accurately solving my problem - my script would trigger when saving but it wasn't actually processing the current document file being edited/saved - it was triggering the script which would scan all my files defined in my configuration file. This means the plugin wasn't getting to control the configuration file either.

---

I got what I wanted! Assuming the context I have in my question (eg. your project has friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer required in composer):

1. Make an edit to your .zshrc or .bashrc file with snippet below
2. Install the Simple PHP CS Fixer extension & update with desired settings

#### Make Edit to your .zshrc or .bashrc

This [source](https://hub.docker.com/r/ypereirareis/php-cs-fixer) gave me the idea to store `php-cs-fixer` in my `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file like this:

```
php-cs-fixer () {
  docker run -it --rm --net host -v `pwd`:/app  ypereirareis/php-cs-fixer fix --level=psr2 --verbose $@
}
```

**Adapted to my circumstance**:

I pasted this into the bottom of my `.zshrc` file:

```
php-cs-fixer () {
    docker exec -t "mycontainername" /var/www/site/app/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --verbose --config=/var/www/site/.php_cs $@
}
```

- mycontainername can be retrieved by: `docker ps` and looking at last column "Names"
- `/var/www/site/app/` is the container's path to my project's app folder where my composer.json file is
- `/var/www/site/.php_cs` is the container's path to my project's .php_cs file which is at the root of my project eg. `~/code/project/.php_cs`

---

#### Install Simple PHP CS FIXER

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=calebporzio.simple-php-cs-fixer) for vscode makes it easy. I assume it will just call "php-cs-fixer" and the edit your profile will find that function and run the docker stuff for you.

Here are my setting changes:

```
"simple-php-cs-fixer.config": ".php_cs",
"simple-php-cs-fixer.save": true,
```

---

#### BONUS Note:

My .php_cs file in case anyone is curious - I did make my project_path relative to the container and not my host machine.

```
<?php

use PhpCsFixer\Config;
use PhpCsFixer\Finder;

$rules = [
    'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
    'binary_operator_spaces' => [
        'default' => 'single_space',
        'operators' => ['=>' => null],
    ],
    'blank_line_after_namespace' => false,
    'blank_line_after_opening_tag' => false,
    // 'blank_line_before_statement' => [
    //     'statements' => ['return'],
    // ],
    'braces' => true,
    'cast_spaces' => true,
    'class_attributes_separation' => [
        'elements' => ['method'],
    ],
    'class_definition' => true,
    'concat_space' => [
        'spacing' => 'one',
    ],
    'declare_equal_normalize' => true,
    'elseif' => true,
    'encoding' => true,
    'full_opening_tag' => true,
    'fully_qualified_strict_types' => true, // added by Shift
    'function_declaration' => true,
    'function_typehint_space' => true,
    'heredoc_to_nowdoc' => true,
    'include' => true,
    'increment_style' => ['style' => 'post'],
    'indentation_type' => true,
    'linebreak_after_opening_tag' => false,
    'line_ending' => true,
    'lowercase_cast' => true,
    'lowercase_constants' => true,
    'lowercase_keywords' => true,
    'lowercase_static_reference' => true, // added from Symfony
    'magic_method_casing' => true, // added from Symfony
    'magic_constant_casing' => true,
    'method_argument_space' => true,
    'native_function_casing' => true,
    'no_alias_functions' => true,
    'no_extra_blank_lines' => [
        'tokens' => [
            'extra',
            'throw',
            'use',
            'use_trait',
        ],
    ],
    'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening' => false,
    'no_blank_lines_after_phpdoc' => true,
    'no_closing_tag' => true,
    'no_empty_phpdoc' => true,
    'no_empty_statement' => true,
    'no_leading_import_slash' => true,
    'no_leading_namespace_whitespace' => true,
    'no_mixed_echo_print' => [
        'use' => 'echo',
    ],
    'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
    'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => [
        'strategy' => 'no_multi_line',
    ],
    'no_short_bool_cast' => true,
    'no_singleline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
    'no_spaces_after_function_name' => true,
    'no_spaces_around_offset' => true,
    'no_spaces_inside_parenthesis' => true,
    'no_trailing_comma_in_list_call' => true,
    'no_trailing_comma_in_singleline_array' => true,
    'no_trailing_whitespace' => true,
    'no_trailing_whitespace_in_comment' => true,
    'no_unneeded_control_parentheses' => true,
    'no_unreachable_default_argument_value' => true,
    'no_useless_return' => true,
    'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array' => true,
    'no_whitespace_in_blank_line' => true,
    'normalize_index_brace' => true,
    'not_operator_with_successor_space' => true,
    'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
    'ordered_imports' => ['sortAlgorithm' => 'alpha'],
    'phpdoc_indent' => true,
    'phpdoc_inline_tag' => true,
    'phpdoc_no_access' => true,
    'phpdoc_no_package' => true,
    'phpdoc_no_useless_inheritdoc' => true,
    'phpdoc_scalar' => true,
    'phpdoc_single_line_var_spacing' => true,
    'phpdoc_summary' => true,
    'phpdoc_to_comment' => true,
    'phpdoc_trim' => true,
    'phpdoc_types' => true,
    'phpdoc_var_without_name' => true,
    'psr4' => true,
    'self_accessor' => true,
    'short_scalar_cast' => true,
    'simplified_null_return' => false, // disabled by Shift
    'single_blank_line_at_eof' => true,
    'single_blank_line_before_namespace' => false,
    'single_class_element_per_statement' => true,
    'single_import_per_statement' => true,
    'single_line_after_imports' => true,
    'single_line_comment_style' => [
        'comment_types' => ['hash'],
    ],
    'single_quote' => true,
    'space_after_semicolon' => true,
    'standardize_not_equals' => true,
    'switch_case_semicolon_to_colon' => true,
    'switch_case_space' => true,
    'ternary_operator_spaces' => true,
    'trailing_comma_in_multiline_array' => true,
    'trim_array_spaces' => true,
    'unary_operator_spaces' => true,
    'visibility_required' => [
        'elements' => ['method', 'property'],
    ],
    'whitespace_after_comma_in_array' => true,
];

$project_path = '/var/www/site/app';
$finder = Finder::create()
    ->in([
        $project_path . '/app',
        $project_path . '/config',
        $project_path . '/database',
        $project_path . '/resources',
        $project_path . '/routes',
        $project_path . '/tests',
    ])
    ->name('*.php')
    ->notName('*.blade.php')
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreVCS(true);

return Config::create()
    ->setFinder($finder)
    ->setRules($rules)
    ->setRiskyAllowed(true)
    ->setUsingCache(false);
```

Comment: I will update this when I learn more about making this more "multi-project" friendly, but for now my advice is to make your vscode settings based per folder or workspace and not by user to avoid complications!

Comment: This is the stuff I hate about Linux, if we want something like what you did, we have to end up with a horrible alias, this is more complex than it seems to set up than just installing PHP and the plugin... but well... this is what we have... Thanks for sharing your solution !

Comment: Yes, but if we have to setup PHP, it's annoying to have to change versions to support different projects - and makes provisioning harder for onboarding new/junior developers. I agree that this is way more complicated than it should be. And I'm not 100% sold on my on solution yet for exactly this versatility reason.

Comment: No, you only need to have PHP locally, and also have PHP CS Fixer locally, then, for any project, you must use docker and use any version you like, you can have both, but PHP will be on docker and PHP CS on your machine...

Comment: Can't you just use the VSCode Remote WSL and/or Containers extension and install PHP CS fixer as a dev dependency? Then just define the path as it is used inside the container?

Comment: For what is worth, I just abandoned this whole idea LOL - and I ended up with vscode settings ```{
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
}``` Also I like the plugin PHP intelephense for getting around functions and highlighting PHP code issues.

Comment: @amurell So you dumped the approach? I just stumbled across this question as I am trying to achieve the same setup (php-cs-fixer in docker container) due to different project setups.

Comment: @NeleKosog Yeah I gave up on getting php-cs-fixer working through the docker container. However, most of what I wanted (syntax highlighting, IDE tracing, and some fixes on save) I was able to achieve with plugin: `bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client` and also using vscode settings - `"editor.tabSize": 4`, `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {"source.fixAll": true}`,
  `"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true`,
  `"files.insertFinalNewline": true`. I left this answer here for folks who want to solve it in case it leads them to the things that will work for their setup.

Answer (score 3):

I come with my 2 cents for vscode, as I gave up on using any php-cs-fixer related extension.

Install this extensions
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave.

Basically, it allows you to run *any* command when saving a file; it is not targeted specifically to php fixer

Then, in workspace's or folder's settings, setup a command to forward instruction on saved file, using extension's placeholder.
`{containerName}` is the name of the container you want to forward command to, `${relativeFile}` is the extension's placeholder for the relative path of the saved file.

```js
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": ".php",
            "cmd": "docker exec -i {containerName} /var/www/html/tools/php-cs-fixer/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer --format=json fix ${relativeFile}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Make sure to set the appropriate path (inside the container) of php-cs-fixer executable.

Comment: I found this to a be a simpler solution than fiddling with the various CS Fixer extensions. On Windows however, Run On Save passes the path of the file with backslashes, which CS Fixer in the container doesn't like. So I had to come up with this work around using powershell to replace the slashes. `powershell docker exec -i containername tools/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --config tools/php-cs-fixer.php_cs ('${relativeFile}' -replace '\\\\','/')`

Answer (score 0):

As part of a package solution for overall application code quality control ([interitty/code-checker](https://gitlab.com/interitty/code-checker)), I solved the situation of running a [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) inside a docker container from [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.apache.org) on a guest machine.

So, I created a [bash script](https://gitlab.com/interitty/code-checker/-/blob/main/bin/php-cs-fixer) that emulates the php-cs-fixer interface and passes the parameters to the specified container.

Related documentation can be found in the [readme](https://gitlab.com/interitty/code-checker/-/tree/main#php-coding-standards-fixer)

I hope that this should help you too.